# How can I map my species occurrence data?

Tags: r

I found a tutorial on ROpenSci for overlaying species occurrence data with climate data: https://ropensci.org/blog/2014/04/22/rwbclimate-sp/
I'm trying to make a species occurrence map of three plant species using the R package rWBClimate. I would like to use a climate model to project future species occurrence distribution based on climate variabilities (temperature).

I know how to get model temperatures and I've used the subset function, but every time I use the climate_map function I get an error saying "Error in climate_map(usmex.basin, temp.dat, return_map = F) : 
  You can't have more than one piece of data for each region to map".

Does any one know how to fix this error?

Codes:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("ropensci/rWBclimate")
library("rWBclimate")
library("spocc")
library("plyr")
library("sp")
dir.create("~/kmltmp")
options(kmlpath="~/kmltmp")
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
require(rWBclimate)
usmex <- c(273:284, 328:365) 
usmex.basin <- create_map_df(usmex)
temp.dat <- get_model_temp(usmex, type= "mavg", 2080, 2100) 
#mavg=monthly averages #2080 is start year #2100 is end year

temp.dat <- subset(temp.dat, temp.dat$year ==2080) #for year 2080
temp.dat <- subset(temp.dat, temp.dat$gcm=="ukmo_hadcm3") 
#general circulation model name ukmo_hadcm3
temp.dat <- subset(temp.dat, temp.dat$scenario!="b1") 
#b1 scenario with a more ecologically friendly world
usmex.map.df <- climate_map(usmex.basin, temp.dat, return_map =F)           
#return_map=F bc i need a dataframe where data items are matched to their     
 polygon that I can plot later on.
**Error in climate_map(usmex.basin, temp.dat, return_map = F) : 
You can't have more than one piece of data for each region to map**

#Plant species:
splist <- c("Acanthospermum australe", 
"Abutilon megapotamicum", "Alternanthera philoxeroides")
splist <-sort(splist)
require("spocc")
out <- occ(query=splist, from= "gbif", limit=100)
out <-fixnames(out, how="query")
out_df <- occ2df(out) #combine results from occ calls to a single data.frame
```

Comment: Check out this issue and the solution, it matches yours:
https://github.com/ropensci/rWBclimate/issues/29

Comment: @Amar Thanks, I saw this on github too. I worked through it, but I'm getting a character(0) message when I apply the solution mentioned in that site. The character(0) message means that no data is missing. The solution didn't work for my particular case.